# N50 347Y Transistor? High-voltage transformer circuit component

Tags: transistors, transformer, ac, bjt, inverter

recently came across a 15kV inverter for a DC high-voltage transformer kit that comes with the attached circuitry. I already have most of the components on hand, though I am unsure on what the 'N50 347 Y' is. To me it seemed like a transistor, though I can't find this component in anywhere, not even a datasheet. Does anyone know what transistor model is this or what equivalent model is this?

[image]

Comment: One Google search was all it took. When searching for components sometimes missing off the last letter can help.

Comment: Yup, I already tried that and my search result is just random transistors

Comment: @RoyC:  If you found it, you might as well post it as an answer.  I tried, and couldn't find anything that looked reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

It's on Alibaba as N50 347Y "booster coil companion chip" in 20-piece quantity - the usual caveats apply.

Comment: Is there any data sheet? As if N50 347Y is a common model there should be numerous manufacturers? Or could it possible be that this particular model is built specifically for this schematic?

Answer (score -1):

npn D882. This is the one. Dont know why they have it under n50.

Comment: What makes you think it's a [2SD882](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/2sd882.pdf)? According to the datasheet the marking should read _D882_.